# My public var is invisible to its cousin

Tags: android, android-preferences

Inspired by Magenta's book "Learning Android," I've created an Application class for my app:

```
public class KITAppClass extends Application implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

      private static final String TAG = KITAppClass.class.getSimpleName();
      //private SharedPreferences KITPrefs;
          public SharedPreferences KITPrefs;        
. . .
```

However, now I'm getting "KITPrefs cannot be resolved" on this line in a different class file that references the SharedPreferences:

```
allContacts.setSelected(KITPrefs.getBoolean("allContacts", false));
```

I'm wondering: if the prefs are shared, why were they marked "private" in the example code?
Why is it still not seen, even after I marked it "public"?

If I add "import KITAppClass;" I get virtually paddled with "The import KITAppClass cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
public class KITAppClass extends Application implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    ...
    protected static SharedPreferences kitPrefs;
    ...
}
```

Then access `kitPrefs` from the `Activity` (or other) classes in the app (assuming they occupy the same namespace) using, for example...

```
KITAppClass.kitPrefs.getBoolean(...);
```

In saying that, maintaining an instance of a `SharedPreferences` at the `Application` class level isn't nesessary as you can get the `SharedPreferences` from any `Activity` at any time. See [Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Also, think twice about actually extending `Application` unless you really have to and unless you really know what you're doing with it. In the majority of cases (for simple apps at least) it isn't necessary. Just because they show you how to do it in a book doesn't mean  you need to do it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked; also, you have succeeded in making me doubt the wisdom or necessity of extending Application. However, this is what I was thinking (please let me know if this does/not make sense): My app's only GUI are the Preferences screens. Otherwise, everything the app does is accomplished "behind the scenes." The app is started via a BroadcastReceiver that will listen for the phone's OnBoot() event (or whatever it's called), and then CONDITIONALLY start 0, 1, or 2 Services (depending on the value of certain Preferences items).

Comment: Part II:  In this way, the Application subclass is initialized from the git-go...hmmm, yes, I guess the Services can simply reference the Preferences on an as-needed basis without requiring an Application subclass to instantiate it/them...

Comment: @Clay: There is no real right or wrong when it comes to extending `Application` - you really just need to decide if it's necessary or not. If it's not then it means you're saddled with maintaining yet another bit of code. If you can tie your components together without it then leave it out. If things get complex then extending `Application` may well be the best way to go as it can act as an anchor with `static` references to helper classes and so on but you need to look at that on a per-case basis. Anyway, glad I was able to help. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

To access `KITPrefs` from other `Activity` class you can use the `getApplicationContext()` and cast your `Application` class.

```
((KITAppClass)getApplicationContext()).KITPrefs.getBoolean("allContacts", false);
```